# new instance is not instanceof itself

Tags: javascript

```
function f(){
    return f;
}
console.log(new f() instanceof f);
```

The snippet above is giving false as output. How can it happen?

Answer (score 3):

The function `f` is returning the reference to itself. Don't return anything from the function. So, by default the function context `this` will be returned.

`new f()` will return the reference to `f` which clearly is not instance of `f`(itself).

```js
function f() {
    // No need to return anything

    // return this is implicit
}

console.log(new f() instanceof f);
```

Comment: or return any primitive

Comment: when i am returning anything inside the constructor other than an object or function it is acting fine as expected . why so ?

Answer (score 2):

`f` that you are returning is not an instance, it's function/constructor `f`, instead of `return f` do `return this` - this will be instance of `f`

Comment: or don't return anything, this is implied

Comment: or return any  primitive